# how to fill missing values with non missing values of same column for identical values of two other columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

My dataframe looks as follows:

```
              date currency  exchange_rate
222     1987-05-01      USD         1.0000
226     2019-11-01      AUD         1.4730
           ...      ...            ...
1455221 2019-10-01      AUD         1.4710
1455222 2019-11-01      AUD            NaN
```

For every NaN in the column exchange_rate I want to fill it with a value with the same values in currency and date.
So I want it to look as follows:

```
              date currency  exchange_rate
222     1987-05-01      USD         1.0000
226     2019-11-01      AUD         1.4730
           ...      ...            ...
1455221 2019-10-01      AUD         1.4710
1455222 2019-11-01      AUD         1.4730
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get first non missing value per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and then repalce misisng values by them:

```
s = df.groupby(['date', 'currency'])['exchange_rate'].transform('first')
df['exchange_rate'] = df['exchange_rate'].fillna(s)
```

Or:

```
df['exchange_rate'] = df['exchange_rate'].combine_first(s)
```

---

```
print (df)
               date currency  exchange_rate
222      1987-05-01      USD          1.000
226      2019-11-01      AUD          1.473
1455221  2019-10-01      AUD          1.471
1455222  2019-11-01      AUD          1.473
```

Test if first value per froup is `NaN`:

```
print (df)
               date currency  exchange_rate
222      1987-05-01      USD          1.000
226      2019-11-01      AUD            NaN
1455221  2019-10-01      AUD          1.471
1455222  2019-11-01      AUD         50.000


s = df.groupby(['date', 'currency'])['exchange_rate'].transform('first')
df['exchange_rate'] = df['exchange_rate'].fillna(s)
print (df)
               date currency  exchange_rate
222      1987-05-01      USD          1.000
226      2019-11-01      AUD         50.000
1455221  2019-10-01      AUD          1.471
1455222  2019-11-01      AUD         50.000
```

Comment: what if first value of group is `nan`?

Comment: @deadshot - Then using first non NaN value, tested.

Comment: @jezrael Do you mean by your comment that if the first value is a NaN it will get filled by the first suitable non NaN value?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
df['exchange_rate'] = df.groupby(['date', 'Currency'])['exchange_rate'].apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())
```